# ExtendedListView not scrolling to correct position

Tags: xamarin.android

I have an `ExtendedListView` held in a fragment. The fragment is implemented correctly and the `ListView` itself is popululated fine.

The listview contains a number of groups, all of which are not expanded when the view is populated. I click on a group and click on an item. Both the item position and group number are stored and some data is displayed in a new view. The view has a return button which when clicked returns to the list view.

When I return to the fragment, the list is populated and the stored group is opened. The issue comes though with using `SmoothScrollToPosition` - it doesn't work. The list will scroll but as the data is in a group, the item is usually off the screen, albeit, it's the next item if you scroll the list down.

It seems as if the group number itself is affecting where the SmoothScroll lands.

Am I using the `SmoothScrollToPosition` correctly for groups within a scroll view or do I need to use some sort of offset depending on the group number within the `ExtedListView`?  I've seen various posts on here saying there is a known bug in the Java implementation so wondered if that had fed through to the .NET for Android code.

Comment: To help others better understand your question, you may add some relevant code. By the way, do you mean you use [ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView)?